# shindig error: At least 1 ModulePrefs is required

Tags: opensocial, apache-shindig

I have Shindig 2.0.2 server running. When I'm trying to render the following local gadget spec XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Calendar">
    <Require feature="opensocial-0.7" />
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="url" href='../../Base/content/calendar/index.html'>

  </Content>
</Module>
```

I get this error:

> At least 1 ModulePrefs is required.

Does anyone knows this error?

Also when I run my server localy, there is no problem. The error occurs only when my app and Shindig are deployed on cloud (under https).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Shindig got the SAML redirection HTML page so it could not be parsed correctly.